# Update Javascript version to ES6 in WSO2 with Nashorn

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-integration-studio, wso2-micro-integrator

I'm using js functions and features in Wso2 integration studio for coding API. But I have to use Js ES6. Is it possible? If not, can I use ES6 features in Nashornjs?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should be able to use ES6 features with Nashorn. Make sure you have a JDK that supports ES6 and then on server startup set the following runtime arg. You can add the following to the `micro-integrator.sh`.

```
-Dnashorn.args=--language=es6
```

Also, you must use the script as an external script picked from the registry. Something like below. Otherwise, Integration Studio will not let you save ES6 syntax.

```xml
<script function="test" key="gov:scripts/script.js" language="nashornJs">
    <include key="script"/>
</script>
```